# Mockito - InjectMocks or how to get new value after method invocation

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I have the following class:

```
public class DaoService {
   private Dao dao;
   private Map<String, Entity> map;

   public DaoService(Dao dao, Map<String, Entity> map){
       this.dao = dao;
       this.map = map;
   }

   public create(Entity entity){
      Dao.create(entity);
      map.put(Entity.getName(), entity);
   }
}
```

I want to test that the method invocation realy put a new element in the map and  when I invoke It more with another paramter It will have size equals 2. But I need to ignore Dao.create().

I have the following test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DaoServiceTest {
   @Mock
   Dao dao;

   @Mock
   Map<String, Entity> map = new HashMap<>();

   @InjectMocks
   DaoService service;

   @Test
   public void testCreate(){
      Entity entity = new Entity("Alex");   // name
      service.create(entity);
      assertEquals(map.size(),1);   // failNotEquals
   }
```

How can I do when I invoke `service.create(entity)` that It will ignore `dao.create(entity)` but will not ignore `map.put(entity.getName(), entity)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you annotate the `map` with `@Mock` and so you are calling `map.size()` on a mock, not on the `HashMap` you've assigned to `map`. What you want here is to spy on the `map` initialized with `HashMap`. So you can just write

```
@Spy
Map<String, Entity> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Or you may not use `@InjectMocks` and inject `Dao` mock and regular `HashMap` manually. This way the assertion will work as well. WRT ignoring `dao.create(entity)`, it's ignored by design of Mockito unless you configure it otherwise